# Finding the calling controller/action in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Like request.referer, I want to know from which controller/action the user is coming from. Is there a method do to this? All I could think of is to use a flash, any better method?

Comment: Why do you need to know this?

Comment: I'm doing some actions based on the request.referer. It was working fine until I added some validations returning a render :action on errors. I loose the URI referrer information when doing a render.

Comment: I solved my problem by checking for values in params, looking for the form attributes.

Comment: Find the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4926906/rails-validation-conditional-redirect

Works for me

Answer (score 5):

Rails.application.routes.recognize_path(request.referer)[:action]