# Rails validation conditional redirect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I am currently having an issue with how Rails is performing and responding to a validation result. I have a user registration form. The user could hit this form in two different places. They could hit the form from the homepage or from `users/new`. Both forms will post to the same place as I am trying to keep it DRY.

The `users/new` page works as is expected. If the user has a validation issue it will return and populate the form. Where I get a problem is on the home page. If a user has a validation issue it now redirects to the `users/new` page. I would much prefer that when on the home page I would return the user to that same page and show the validation results there.  Is there a way in the controller to redirect to the form the user was at?

```
def create
  @user = User.new(params[:user])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @user.save
      format.html { redirect_to(@user, :notice => 'User was successfully created.') }
      format.xml  { render :xml => @user, :status => :created, :location => @user }
    else
      format.html { render :action => "new" } # I'm thinking I can do something here?
      format.xml  { render :xml => @user.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

I have tried to change the `render :action => 'new'` line to redirect to the user url but it hasn't worked. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: So, when the user has a validation issue on the home page, it doesn't redirect, it just renders the wrong view... right?

Comment: Correct. Validation issues will cause the user to always go to the users form. Even if the originating form was on the index page. Unfortunately the requirements specify users can register from two places.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I would add querystring parameters to the URL it is posting to with the controller and action that it came from with something like this:

```
# Using form_tag
<%= form_tag user_path(@user, :controller_name => controller.controller_name, :action_name => controller.action_name) do %>

# Using form_for
<%= form_for @user, :url => user_path(@user, :controller_name => controller.controller_name, :action_name => controller.action_name) do %>
```

Then, you can update that line in the `create` action of your controller like this:

```
render '#{params[:controller_name]}/#{params[:action_name]}'
```

**Update**

I just realized that using the code above, will render the correct view the first time validation fails, but if validation fails a second time, it will try to render the `users/create` view. If this is the route you want to take, you should not use `controller.controller_name`, etc in the view, but assign `@controller_name` correctly and use that variable instead.  However, this only adds to the 'overkill' comment made by Xavier.

Comment: I've been thinking about this too, and ran into the same problem with my code.  Validation fails twice, and mine loses its place forever; yours can be tweaked to work:  Replace `:controller_name => controller.controller_name` with `:controller_name => params[:controller_name] || params[:controller]` (and likewise with `:action`), so it'll only use the current controller and action if it hasn't seen them before - i.e. the first time we load the form.  I still think it's a lot of code, but it works, and I sure can't think of a simpler way...  Upvote - cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Art's on the right track, but you can't use a redirect, as you need the instance variable `@user` that's set in your controller, which'll be lost on a new HTTP request (because ever request is handled by a new, clean controller instance).

But you can use the referer information yourself, and use that to pick the right page to render:

```
render :action => (request.referer =~ /\/users\/new/)? :new : :index
```

Note:  Another answer popped up while I was posting that suggests adding the old controller / action fields to your form, but that seems like overkill to me - you already have all the information you need in `request.referer`.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I agree with you. It may be overkill.  However, it prevents you from having to worry about the name of the route (/users/new), which is unlikely to change, but may change (/users/signup, /users/register, etc).  Also, it provides an easy way to make this work on more than the two pages.  Again, it may never be a requirement to do so, but it might.  Still, I totally understand the argument for overkill.  I'm 6's on this one right now.

Comment: @dontangg  That's a good point - even in an action with a normal "Railsy" URL, that's a nasty mystery bug waiting to happen in a few months' time...  It would be nice if you could do something like `old_params = parameterize(request.referer)`, and then just `render :action => old_params[:action]` - I'm poking around for this on Google, but it doesn't look promising...  Cheers!

Comment: Just found something. You can use ` path = ActionController::Routing::Routes.recognize_path(request.referer)`. Then you can just `render '#{path[:controller]}/#{path[:action]}'`. However, you'd still have to worry about the second time validation fails, right? Because then, the action will be `create`, right?  PS. I don't think that this works in Rails 3 because it is now `ActionDispatch::Routing`.

Comment: You can use `Rails.application.routes.recognize_path` in Rails 3.

Comment: @dontangg  I found that too, but it wouldn't work for me (Rails 2.3.8) if I passed it the whole URL - it threw a RoutingError!  I eventually figured out how to pull the URL minus the domain via `Rack::MockRequest.env_for(request.referer)['PATH_INFO']` (A regex would probably have worked, but I was trying to be legit).  but even then, `recognize_path` wouldn't work for me unless I specified a (hardcoded) HTTP verb, which you just can't get from the referer string.  I gave up at that point - being unable to tell GET:/users from POST:/users just won't cut it here.

Answer (score 0):

Try `redirect_to :back`
It's a shorthand for `redirect_to(request.env["HTTP_REFERER"])`

oops, it only works for success. sorry

well, then you have to check inside the block (after format.html) where he came from (by looking at request.env["HTTP_REFERER"]) and render respective action.

Comment: While that takes me to the correct page, the validation does not get set when doing that. By redirecting I've lost the error messages.